# How to interrupt server request programmatically in liferay

Tags: servlets, liferay

While doing an export to Excel files the user needs to be able to stop the current export action.

Is there any way to do that programmatically in Liferay?

Here is the expected scenario:

1. The user clicks on "Cancel export"
2. The action is canceled

I'm working with Liferay 6.2 and for Excel I'm using the POI library.

P.S. The export action makes several requests to the database in order to read data and write it to excel file (in a loop).

Comment: This is not specific to Liferay or POI. The interesting thing is: What part of the request consumes the most time? The database access, the excel generation, or the loop? If it is the database access, my answer here could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931835/how-to-cancel-a-running-sql-query/33988897 . Otherwise you could send the thread an _interrupt_ event and check that in the loop condition.

Comment: The loop takes most of the time because it makes several calls to the database (each call takes up to 1.2 seconds). The thread will be interrupted for actual user and not for others, isn't it ?

Comment: The thread is interrupted for the actual _request_.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Can you please provide links to achieve this behaviour ? I don't know how to achieve this in liferay

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by my answer to [How to cancel a running SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988897/4371659)

```
public void export() {
  // Store the current thread in the HttpSession
  HttpSession httpSession = servletRequest.getSession()
  httpSession.setAttribute("exportThread", Thread.currentThread());

  try {
    // Run your export loop
    for (...) {
      if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Export was called
        return;
      }

      // Do your export
      ...
    }

  } finally {
    // Clear the session attribute, if it is still our thread
    if (httpSession.getAttribute("exportThread") == Thread.currentThread()) {
      httpSession.removeAttribute("exportThread");
    }
  }
}

public void cancel() {
  // Get the thread from the HTTP session
  HttpSession httpSession = servletRequest.getSession();
  Thread exportThread = (Thread) httpSession.getAttribute("exportThread");
  if (exportThread != null) {
    // Cancel the previous export
    exportThread.interrupt();
  }
}
```

Biggest problem: the session is not serializable with a thread attached to it. But as long as you don't try to serialize the session (e.g. in a cluster) there is no problem with this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will try this solution and keep you updated.